# Searching Within Parent Entries

Tags: relationships

I have some parent entries that I am looking to filter down using a date field.  I know the search functions are not available in the parent or relationship fields.  What other options do I have?

I was thinking of doing a separate entries tag, but have not found a way to select all entries that are related to another specific entry, like this:

{exp:channel:entries search:parent_entry="1234"}

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your relationships are setup, and exactly ow you want to filter them? Maybe give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can get all your parent entry ids into another channel entry tag.

1.) Create a Template with your parent channel tag and pass an embed variable to it from your main template. Here you can add any parameter you need to get the needed data.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="parent" entry_id="{embed:eid}" }
    <h1>Parent Data</h1>
{/exp:channel:entries
```

2.) Embed the above template in your main template. And pass the parent entry_ids into the embeded template.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="child"}
   {embed="template/parent-entries" eid="{parents channel="parent" backspace="1"}{entry_id}|{/parents"}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```